# Data structure that inserts in constant time at endpoints and before/after an element?

Tags: java, performance, list

I am looking for a data structure that:

- Has an unbounded size.
- Maintains the insertion order of its elements.
- Inserts efficiently at the beginning and end of the list (ideally in constant time).
- Inserts efficiently before or after an existing element (ideally in constant time).

I ruled out `ArrayList` because it isn't efficient at inserting at the beginning of the list.

On the surface `LinkedList` should be a perfect match, but in practice the Java implementation isn't efficient at inserting before or after existing elements (i.e. it walks the entire list to find the insertion position).

(I don't personally need to store duplicate elements but others might)

---

**Motivation**: I am building an event queue that allows occasional cheating (inserting before or after an existing event).

Comment: LinkedHashMap ?

Comment: @ACV How can you insert before or after existing elements?

Comment: Depends on how you detect the "existing element" you want to insert before/after given the element you want to insert.

Comment: Are duplicates allowed?

Comment: @user7 yeah, as khachik says, you need to define a good key first for this to work

Comment: @user7 I've updated the question.

Comment: @ACV I don't think it is impossible to design "a good key" for this use-case. You'd need to simultaneously guarantee that one key shows up before another, and allow an unlimited number of nodes to be inserted between them.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with just writing your own linked list? It's not a particularly difficult data structure to implement, and will tick all your boxes.

Comment: How many events do you plan to have?  And how often will events be cheating?  I don't think a `LinkedList` is that bad in this case.

Comment: @Gili You didn't provide enough data, but LinkedHashMap guarantees order and you can insert as many as you like - just youse the hashCode of your objects as a key. Devise a hashCode function that would reflect the order.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Right. If I don't find an existing implementation, that might be the ideal option.

Comment: @ACV `LinkedHashMap` preserves insertion order. It is impossible let's say insert new element into `LinkedHashMap` before 3rd or 10th element in that map.

Comment: @ACV I suggest posting a formal answer and letting people comment there. Otherwise this will pollute the main comments of this question.

Comment: (Note that if you're considering a hashing datastructure, you're going to need to implement both `hashCode` and `equals`, which may invalidate your "update" claim)

Comment: So many comments, but nobody telling you about *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: @GhostCat I appreciate you explaining why you think this is off-topic but I will point out that thus far there hasn't been a single good solution (short of "write your own") so I don't think I am actually getting opinionated answers here. People are honestly looking to provide a solution and it seems there isn't one as of today.

Comment: I am merely saying that while you have that "is there a 3rd party lib" sentence in there, your question *should* be closed as off topic,  no matter how much good stuff comes in. That also opens the door for (at some point) seeing the question being deleted. Just saying ...

Comment: Just edit the "3rd party" out. Simply ask "How can I...?". If the simplest solution is using a library, someone will tell you not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @maaartinus Done. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

Honestly I think a custom implementation of a `LinkedList` would be the way to go:

- Has an unbounded size.

  - Yes.
- Maintains the insertion order of its elements.

  - Yes.
- Inserts efficiently at the beginning and end of the list (ideally in constant time).

  - Yes, and O(1).
- Inserts efficiently before or after an existing element (ideally in constant time).

  - If you maintain a `Map<?, Node>` when inserting/removing elements, then you can access a `Node` (and its previous/next Nodes) in constant time and insert/remove that way.

Depending on the total amount of events (and how often events can cheat), linear time could be considered as well, allowing you to use the API's implementation of `LinkedList`.

Comment: The crux of the problem is that the Java API does not expose the nodes of a linked list. This prevents one from saying "insert before/after this node" which would be efficient. `LinkedList.listIterator()` actually does allow efficient inserts before/after but the iterator gets invalidated by `addFirst()`, `addLast()`.

Comment: Even if the API did expose the nodes, you wouldn't be able to randomly access them.

Comment: You can use a HashMap for that. It's still constant time.

Comment: @JacobG.I didn't ask for random access and in fact I don't actually need it. I just need to be able to read the front of the list in constant time.

Comment: @thatotherguy I have yet to see a Map-oriented answer that guarantees insertion ordering and allows one to insert an unlimited number of nodes between two existing nodes.

Comment: @Gili `LinkedList#peekFirst` reads the front of the list in constant time.

Comment: @Gili The hash table is used in conjunction with the linked list, to allow you to look up the link node for the given id and insert there.

Comment: @Gili Then you would need to maintain a `Map<?, Node>` where `Node` contains both its previous and next nodes.

Comment: @thatotherguy Can you please flesh this out in a separate answer?

Comment: @JacobG. Yes, so essentially if performance of the built-in `LinkedList` is insufficient for my use-case (I will check with a profiler) then I should consider implementing my own linked list (which, as others have mentioned doesn't seem so hard).

Answer (score 0):

How about an AVL tree? Since the tree is always balanced, it has a height of O(log(N)) where N is the number of nodes in the tree. This would make the worst case
insertion also O(log(N)).

I believe that's as close to constant time as you can get for what you're looking for. Sorry if this isn't an answer, I don't have a high enough reputation to post a comment yet :/

Comment: `O(log(N))` is not constant time

Comment: @user7 OP said "ideally in constant time"

Comment: That's why I said "as close to constant time as you can get for what you're looking for." I would've left it as a comment if I could've :/

Comment: I prefer answers to comments anyway. Is there an established AVL tree implementation for Java?

Comment: This also cannot maintain insertion order of elements

Comment: You could maintain the insertion order if you add an extra element to the node which stores the order of insertion. If you were to do that though, you'd have to write the data structure yourself and programmatically keep a tally of the insertion of the nodes. It would work less efficiently than a queue, but still more efficiently than a linked list

Answer (score 0):

> I am building an event queue that allows occasional cheating (inserting before or after an existing event).

If cheating is rare, go for your own array-based structure. `java.util.ArrayDeque` handles both ends in O(1), but it can't do insertions in the middle. They can be easily added, but the complexity is O(n).

Note that `LinkedList` is for most operations (due to its terrible data locality) much slower than `ArrayList` and `ArrayDeque`.

---

Let's assume, you badly need the constant time insertion in the middle. Something like

```
insertAfter(existingElement, newElement);
```

The problem with `java.util.LinkedList` is that it has no such operation. All it has is `ListIterator`, which allows you an insertion in the middle, but that only helps when you position your iterator first (O(n)).

So you need your own linked list. The basic implementation is rather trivial, what you additionally need is a direct access to its nodes (the things containing the `next` and `prev` links, rather than the things you `add`). Then maintain a `Map<MyThing, MyListNode>`, which allows you to find the node for `existingElement`. Now you just create a new node for the `newElement`, link it properly (which is basically trivial, but has some corner cases) and update your map.

---

To eliminate the border cases (the first/last/only node), add two dummy nodes (`prefirst` and `postlast`) to your linked list. Obviously, these are the only nodes which won't get stored in your map. They make the implementation pretty trivial, e.g.,

```
void insertAfter(MyThing existingElement, MyThing newElement) {
   Node found = map.get(existingElement);
   if (found == null) throw ...
   Node newNode = new Node(newElement);
   map.put(newElement, newNode);

   // Link newNode where it belongs to.
   newNode.next = found.next;
   newNode.prev = found;

   // Fix links.
   newNode.prev.next = newNode;
   newNode.next.prev = newNode;   
}

void insertFirst(MyThing newElement) {
   Node found = prefirst;

   // All the remaining code is simply copied from above.
   // Factor it out.

   Node newNode = new Node(newElement);
   map.put(newElement, newNode);

   // Link newNode where it belongs to.
   newNode.next = found.next;
   newNode.prev = found;

   // Fix links.
   newNode.prev.next = newNode;
   newNode.next.prev = newNode;   
}
```

Comment: You're right. I've updated the question. I think you have a typo in your answer though. You wrote `Note that LinkedList is for most operations[...]` LinkedList is what? Also, you wrote that `Deque` is `O(n)` for insertions in the middle but as far as I can tell, it does not allow inserting in the middle.

Comment: @Gili Fixed `LinkedList`. And you're right with `Deque`, I actually meant `ArrayDeque` and assumed it also implements `List`, which it does not. So I'd suggest `MyOwnArrayDeque` ;).

Comment: @maaartinus Off-topic, but there are plans to have `ArrayDeque` implement all of the methods in `List` but not implement the interface itself :)

Comment: @JacobG. Funny.  Do you know why? I mean... these methods are surely useful, but tons of useful methods are missing (e.g., `ArrayList.removeLast`) and hardly anything gets added.

Comment: @maaartinus I’ve tried to propose tons of methods to OpenJDK, but they’re very hesitant to add convenience methods for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

- Preserves insertion order
- Is fast (because uses the key to find the element basically in `O(1)`).
- Allows to insert elements whenever you like (but for this you need to think of a good key - devise a `hashCode()` and `equals()` that would make sense for your ordering logic).

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with
>   predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap
>   in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its
>   entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is
>   normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map
>   (insertion-order).

I would go against custom collection because you'll spend a lot of time to reinvent the wheel and then you'll ultimately arrive at the conclusion that it's better to use `LinkedHashMap`.

Please note, this collection is not thread-safe.

Comment: As commented elsewhere, I don't see how you can simultaneously control that key X will up before key Y, and maintain the ability to insert unlimited elements between X and Y. There is only so much you can do with this technique. It will probably work for people who know the maximum number of elements they need to insert between X and Y.

Answer (score -1):

I generally use `forward_list` of c++11 for the operations that require optimal insertions at any positions. It is based on singly linked list. See [forward_list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/forward_list/forward_list/insert_after/).

> Forward lists are sequence containers that allow constant time insert and erase operations anywhere within the sequence.See first sentence of [forward_list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/forward_list/forward_list/)

If optimization is your concern why not switch to c++. I am not sure such feature is present in java. Note that although forward_list offers constant time insertion, you cant access elements directly by the position.

In general for a linked list when you say insert at a position.
There are two cases:

1. You have reference to the node at that position. In this case the time complexity is O(1)
2. You only have the index. Time complexity will be O(n)

Comment: Agreed. `LinkedList` would be an ideal solution for my question except that Java does not expose references to nodes. Hence, we're stuck with a complexity of O(n).